# Best way to "clean up" an old trumpet?

Tags: trumpet, brass

I was given an old student trumpet (and case). It's surprisingly not dented, but looks awful--half the lacquer is gone and mixed with minor surface corrosion. However, it plays OK for a student trumpet. My plan is to pair it with a cheap Chinese mouthpiece and find something useful for it.

It would be nice to at least make it look like it's not infected with a deadly disease.

Any recommendations on how to clean it up without wrecking it?

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a warm bath, blow the water through, clean it with Sigolin or another (not sharp) cleaning product. Is it silver or bronze?  The product  may depend on this. Well, there are special (prepared) cleaning towels. But they are only available in a music shop where they can give you further advice.

https://www.wwbw.com/the-music-room/essential-cleaning-supplies-for-trumpet-players

There are also several youtube tutorials like this: